# Stainless steel wire mesh spot welded to a frame

Tags: mechanical-engineering, welding

Can anybody tell me how to make a similar welding job - that is to spot weld a thin stainless steel wire mesh to a stainless steel frame. What machine and technique  should be used to accomplish this job.

The time has come to replace the torn wire mesh.

Thanks in advance.
[image: spot welded stainless steel wire mesh]

Comment: A spot-welder on a low setting.

Comment: Any specific model of a "spot welder" as I have never seen one. Seen only conventional arc welding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a spot welder but I would consider something like this: [Pistol Grip Single Probe Hand Piece – PG2 with Roll Spot](https://sunstonewelders.com/product/pistol-grip-single-probe-hand-piece-pg2-with-roll-spot/)

But judging from your picture you might want to consider using a different method then welding. There is quite a bit of corrosion which can result from improper welding. If you need support, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks, sir! But $1750 will be hardly approved. The corrosion results from the harsh  atmosphere.